# How to deal with parameter that is array of string in systemverilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

i have a module with a parameter of array type. 
which is :

```
module a # (parameter b [2-1:0] = '{default:"BRAM"})
...
generate
genvar i;
for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1) begin
    sa # (.sb(b[i])) u_sa (
...
endmodule
```

in the top, the code is

```
a #(.b("BRAM0","BRAM1")) u_a (
...
```

but after simulation, i got the value 1'bx in u_a/u_sax/sb ;

how to convey the value "BRAM0" or "BRAM1" to the submodule parameter u_sax/sb ?

thanks for the help~

Answer (score 0):

Why not make parameter `b` a string:

```
module a # (parameter string b [2-1:0] = '{default:"BRAM"});
```

Then you can instantiate module `a` like this:

```
  a #(.b('{"BRAM0","BRAM1"})) u_a ();
```

---

When asking a question on Stack Overflow, it is helpful to those answering to supply an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3QMw

```
module a # (parameter string b [2-1:0] = '{default:"BRAM"});

  initial
    foreach (b[i])
      $display("b[%0d]= %s", i, b[i]);

endmodule

module M;

  a #(.b('{"BRAM0","BRAM1"})) u_a ();

endmodule
```

Comment: thanks~ I use string but in the verdi, i can't see a string array. Use $display can clarify it, it seems the verdi 's display issue...